# On click show one at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(".cus-nav .navbar-nav > li").click(function(){
    $(this).find(".mega-menu").slideToggle("fast");
 });
```

When I click li the mega menu will open with toggle. When I click another li it open it's mega menu. But 1st mega menu is still open. So I want when click li show only one mega menu at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Could you not just hide all mega menus before showing the one you want?

```
$(".cus-nav .navbar-nav > li").click(function(){
    $(".mega-menu").hide();
    $(this).find(".mega-menu").slideToggle("fast");
});
```

if you need to animate just the one that is opened shut then you could add a class when opening it so you can find it again later

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".navbar-bar > li").click(function() {
        var $showMenu = $(this).find(".mega-menu");
        var openMenu = !$showMenu.hasClass("opened");

        var $closeMenu = $(".mega-menu").filter(".opened");
        $closeMenu.removeClass("opened");
        $closeMenu.slideToggle("fast");

        if(openMenu){
            $showMenu.addClass("opened");
            $showMenu.slideToggle("fast");
        };       
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes open one at a time but toggle not working. It's not closing.

Comment: Use this code and what css have to write for which class ?

Comment: Thanks your link works. But when it click again, it's not closing . Click Menu 1 is not hiding Mega 1.

Comment: I found this link but can't work on mine. it works fine. http://jsfiddle.net/RX5J6/5/

Comment: i edited it to allow clicking on an open menu to close it, but the version you linked to is better.

Comment: It's perfect what i want. But i can't use it on my code. Can't apply.